# How to output result from calculator through IF?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am creating a calculator that takes input from three textfields: first number, operator, and second number. I am trying to make it work so it outputs the result in a line under the calculator, but all I get is "invalid input" which is the else-part of the if-sta

tement. What is wrong with my code?
Here is my HTML:

```
   <div class="container">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   

</head>
<header>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <h2>Math is fun!</h2>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="my-div">
        <h3>Type in the numbers and the operator you want to use:</h3>

    <form id="myform">
        <label for="firstnumber">First number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="n1" name="firstnumber"><br>
        <label for="operator">Operator ( + - * / ):</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="operator" name="operator"><br>
        <label for="secondnumber"> Second number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="n2" name="secondnumber"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="Submit">
      </form>
    
    </div>

      <div class="Result" id="Result"></div>
      <script src="Calculator.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>



</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
    const firstNum = document.getElementById("n1").value;
const mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
const secondNum = document.getElementById("n2").value;
const button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton")
const div1 = document.getElementById("Result")
const myForm = document.getElementById("myform")

function addNumbers(firstNum, secondNum){
    var result = firstNum + secondNum;
    }

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    if (mathOperator === "+"){
      var plusResult = firstNum + secondNum;
      console.log(firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum)
      console.log(firstNum.value, mathOperator.value, secondNum.value)
      const p = document.createElement("div")
    p.innerHTML = "Result: " + plusResult.value
    div1.appendChild(p)
    }
    else if(mathOperator === "-"){
        var subResult = firstNum - secondNum;
        console.log(firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum)
      console.log(firstNum.value, mathOperator.value, secondNum.value)
        const p = document.createElement("div")
        p.innerHTML = "Result: " + subResult.value  
        div1.appendChild(p)
    }
    else if(mathOperator === "*"){
        var mulResult = firstNum * secondNum;
        console.log(firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum)
      console.log(firstNum.value, mathOperator.value, secondNum.value)
        const p = document.createElement("div")
        p.innerHTML = "Result: " + mulResult.value  
        div1.appendChild(p)
    }
    else if(mathOperator === "/"){
        var divResult = firstNum / secondNum;
        console.log(firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum)
      console.log(firstNum.value, mathOperator.value, secondNum.value)
        const p = document.createElement("div")
        p.innerHTML = "Result: " + divResult.value  
        div1.appendChild(p)
    }
    else{
        const p = document.createElement("div")
        p.innerHTML = "Input is invalid."  
        div1.appendChild(p)
    }
    
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed your console logs to make it clear

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton");
const div1 = document.getElementById("Result");
const myForm = document.getElementById("myform");

// You dont need this part
function addNumbers(firstNum, secondNum) {
  var result = firstNum + secondNum;
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Convert to number to get the desired result and define your variables here not outside this event
  const firstNum = Number(document.getElementById("n1").value);
  const secondNum = Number(document.getElementById("n2").value);
  const mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
  let result;

  if (mathOperator == "+") {
    result = firstNum + secondNum;
  } else if (mathOperator === "-") {
    result = firstNum - secondNum;
  } else if (mathOperator === "*") {
    result = firstNum * secondNum;
  } else if (mathOperator === "/") {
    result = firstNum / secondNum;
  } else {
    result = 'Input is invalid';
  }

  const p = document.createElement("div");
  if(isNaN(result)){
    p.innerHTML = result;
  } else {
    p.innerHTML = "Result: " + result;
  }
  div1.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
    <h3>Type in the numbers and the operator you want to use:</h3>
    <form id="myform">
        <label for="firstnumber">First number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="n1" name="firstnumber"><br>
        <label for="operator">Operator ( + - * / ):</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="operator" name="operator"><br>
        <label for="secondnumber"> Second number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="n2" name="secondnumber"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="Result" id="Result"></div>
```

Another way to write your javascript

```
const button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton"),
      div1 = document.getElementById("Result"),
      myForm = document.getElementById("myform");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const firstNum = Number(document.getElementById("n1").value),
        secondNum = Number(document.getElementById("n2").value),
        mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
  let result;

  result = mathOperator === "+" ? firstNum + secondNum 
                            : mathOperator === "-" ? firstNum - secondNum
                            : mathOperator === "/" ? firstNum / secondNum
                            : mathOperator === "*" ? firstNum * secondNum
                            : "Input is invalid";

  div1.innerHTML = isNaN(result) ? result : "Result: " + result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move these code into listener function, or they only run once when the page load, their value will be `undefine`.

```
myForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  const firstNum = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  const mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator").value;
  const secondNum = document.getElementById("n2").value; 
  ....
  ...
  ..
```

2. `document.getElementById("n1").value` will get string, you have to convert them to numbers by `parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value)`.
3. Remove all `.value` in result like `p.innerHTML = "Result: " + subResult.value`.

The code will be like:

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton"),
    div1 = document.getElementById("Result"),
    myForm = document.getElementById("myform"),
    addNumbers = (firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum) => {
        return res =
            mathOperator === '+' ? 'Result: ' + (firstNum + secondNum)
                : mathOperator === '-' ? 'Result: ' + (firstNum - secondNum)
                    : mathOperator === '*' ? 'Result: ' + (firstNum * secondNum)
                        : mathOperator === '/' ? 'Result: ' + (firstNum / secondNum)
                            : 'Input is invalid.'
    }
myForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const firstNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value),
        mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator").value,
        secondNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value),
        p = document.createElement("div");
    p.innerHTML = addNumbers(firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum)
    div1.appendChild(p)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<header>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <h2>Math is fun!</h2>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="my-div">
        <h3>Type in the numbers and the operator you want to use:</h3>
        <form id="myform">
            <label for="firstnumber">First number:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="n1" name="firstnumber"><br>
            <label for="operator">Operator ( + - * / ):</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="operator" name="operator"><br>
            <label for="secondnumber"> Second number:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="n2" name="secondnumber"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="Result" id="Result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you get the value of the operator input when it is empty.

Here is the solution:

```js
const mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator").value; // let move this line into submit form event
// or
const mathOperatorElement = document.getElementById("operator"); // keep this one outside
const mathOperator = mathOperator.value // and this one inside submit form event
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed a bunch of problems.

```js
const firstNum = document.getElementById("n1");
const mathOperator = document.getElementById("operator");
const secondNum = document.getElementById("n2");
const button1 = document.getElementById("mybutton");
const div1 = document.getElementById("Result");
const myForm = document.getElementById("myform");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {

  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(firstNum.value, mathOperator.value, secondNum.value); // Log the current math problem.

  const op = mathOperator.value; // Get the operator.
  const p = document.createElement("div"); // Create an element which will store the result.

  const number1 = Number(firstNum.value);
  const number2 = Number(secondNum.value);

  if (op === "+") {
    p.textContent = "Result: " + (number1 + number2);
  } else if (op === "-") {
    p.textContent = "Result: " + (number1 - number2);
  } else if (op === "*") {
    p.textContent = "Result: " + (number1 * number2);
  } else if (op === "/") {
    p.textContent = "Result: " + (number1 / number2);
  } else {
    p.textContent = "Operator must be '+', '-', '*', or '/'.";
  }
  div1.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  <h3>Type in the numbers and the operator you want to use:</h3>

  <form id="myform">
    <label for="firstnumber">First number:</label><br>
    <input type="number" required id="n1" name="firstnumber"><br>
    <label for="operator">Operator ( + - * / ):</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="operator" pattern="^[+\-*/]$" maxlength="1" required name="operator" title="'+', '-', '*', or '/'"><br>
    <label for="secondnumber"> Second number:</label><br>
    <input type="number" required id="n2" name="secondnumber"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="mybutton" value="Submit">
  </form>

</div>

<div class="Result" id="Result"></div>
<script src="Calculator.js"></script>
```